# I am evaluating the fourier transform of a function + a constant: $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}(f(x)+c)e^{-ikx}dx$ equals what?

Tags: fourier-transform, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

I am evaluating the fourier transform of a function plus a constant $c$:

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}(f(x)+c)e^{-ikx}dx.$$

As a result, I should get the fourier transform of the function $f(x)$ plus a dirac delta:
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}(f(x)+c)e^{-ikx}dx=\hat{f}(k)+c\delta(k).$$

However, I cannot understand whether I am making some mistake or not and the meaning of such a result.

Comment: the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty ce^{-ikt}\, dt$ doesnt exists. And the Dirac delta is not a function, so Im not sure what you mean by $\delta(k)$

Comment: Your result is almost correct, the Fourier transform of $1$ is $\delta$ with your normalization, so you should have $c \delta(k)$.

Comment: @Botond I cannot understand the physical meaning. The Fourier transform can be associated to an energy spectrum. In this case do I have an infinite energy at zero frequency?

Comment: I can't really say anything about it without context. But why don't you ask it on PSE?

Comment: I can only assume you are talking about the physical meaning as I do not see a question otherwise. In that case superimposing $\cos(\omega_0 t)$ with low $\omega_0$ to a signal $f(t)$ will result in a disturbed signal on top. In the frequency domain you will see spikes at $\pm \omega_0$. Think of a low constant frequency bass sound on top of a melody. Now lot $\omega_0 \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: @Diger Therefore, should my constant $c$ create a spike in the energy spectrum? I am asking this since I am interested in the Fourier Transform of $f(x)$ disregarding the constant $c$. However, I only have the sum of $f(x)+c$ without any knowledge of $c$

Comment: `Therefore, should my constant c create a spike in the energy spectrum?` I would guess so...Probably this should be moved to PSE though